# How to plot a number line in TikZ using a set formula for sequence?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to draw a number line in [0,1] such that the nodes are placed at numbers defined by the Bayes' rule (or any specific function). So for an initial value of x' (specified by me), then I want the program to place nodes at every subsequent node x, where x= x'/((1+x')*0.5) and so on until a max x of 1. Here is a MWE that I devised from another similar post:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=none,
        width=\textwidth,
        xmin=0,xmax=1,
        xtick={0,1},
        xticklabels={$0$,$1$},
        xlabel=$\beta$
         ]
 \addplot[samples at={1,...,100},only marks,mark size=0.5,blue] (x/((1+x)*0.5),0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, I don't want it to run using samples but instead at an initial value (that I can specify) and then work its way up to other numbers until x hits 1.

Further, I want to identify these nodes so that I can draw curved arrows between these numbers to signify jumps.

I have tried multiple approaches, but I'm nsuccessful in getting TikZ to plot specific numbers of such a sequence according to a formula with an initial value. I can easily of course solve it all out separately and then plot it, but I don't want to use this ugly brute force method.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would you mind showing us your best attempt, in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: also your formula seems to have error. if not, than please solve/rewrote it in `x=....`.

Comment: I have now made the edits. Please let me know if the question is still unclear. Thanks :)

Comment: A MWE should contain everything that is necessary to be compileable and not just a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is something like what you want. The initial value is set in points, with the `\setlength` statement. I used 0.99pt in the while loop, because the value never reaches 1.

The code has a lot of comments, ask if anything is unclear, or let me know if I misunderstood.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen} % for whiledo
% set initial value
\newlength\MyX
\setlength\MyX{0.1pt}
% counter for giving a different name to each node
\newcounter{XCnt}
\setcounter{XCnt}{1}
% for convenience
\newcommand\XScale{200}
\newcommand\XMax{1}
\begin{document}
Diagram using the values set up in preamble:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, very thin,|-stealth]  (0,0) node[below] {$0$} -- (\XMax*\XScale pt,0) node[below] {$\XMax$};
% basic while loop
\whiledo{\lengthtest{\MyX<0.99pt}}{%
  %draw filled node at x-position given by the \MyX length
  \node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt,fill,circle] (n-\theXCnt) at (\MyX*\XScale,0) {};
  % calculate new length
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MyX}{\MyX/((1+\MyX)*0.5)}
  % add 1 to the naming counter
  \stepcounter{XCnt}
  % to see the values of \MyX in the log, not necessary
  \typeout{\MyX} 
}

% one example to show that the nodes can be referenced
\draw [red,latex-latex] (n-1) to[bend left] (n-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
Then a second diagram, with slightly different equation, different initial value and scale:
\begin{center}
% set different initial value
\setlength\MyX{0.02pt}
% reset node naming counter
\setcounter{XCnt}{1}
% change scale, if necessary
\renewcommand\XScale{50}
\renewcommand\XMax{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, very thin,-stealth] (0,0) -- (\XMax*\XScale pt+3mm,0); % +3mm to extend the line a bit
% draw tick marks:
\foreach \x in {0,...,\XMax}
   \draw [gray,very thin] (\x*\XScale pt,3pt) -- +(0,-6pt) node[below]{$\x$};

\whiledo{\lengthtest{\MyX<3.999pt}}{% note changed limit
  \node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt,fill,circle] (n-\theXCnt) at (\MyX*\XScale,0) {};
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MyX}{\MyX/((1+\MyX)*0.2)}
  \stepcounter{XCnt}
  \typeout{\MyX} 
}

% one example to show that the nodes can be referenced
\draw [red,latex-latex] (n-1) to[bend left] (n-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Thank you so much for the help. I'm still trying to understand the code properly, but I'm confident it works. Can I write to you later with any clarifications on the code?

Comment: @A.Pant Sure, no problem.

Comment: I have finally figured out all the mechanics of the code. Thank you so much for sharing. This is exactly what I wanted. Can I please ask a few quick follow-up questions:
1. Even though you define the counter as as `{XCnt}` , when you use it in the code you use it as `\theXCnt`. I don't follow this bit.
2. How can I define new new initial values for different number lines in the same document? Since this description goes in the preamble, I was wondering how can I define this for every new number line I draw in the same doc.
Thanks again :)

Comment: @A.Pant 1) It's a general thing, that if the counter is named `X`, then the specified representation of the counter (by default the arabic number), is given by `\theX`. 2) `\setlength` can be used outside the preamble as well, so simply add a `\setlength\MyX{x pt}` before each diagram.

Comment: @A.Pant I updated the code to include a second example where I changed most of the values. I did also make a couple of other additions, to generalize it a bit more, and showed a method for adding numbered ticks along the line.